# Image of a hand with an eye by in the palm. What's the source?

Tags: symbols-symbology, superstition

Why do some Jews wear a necklace with a form of a hand with some sort of eyeball image in the palm of the hand? What is the source for this and when did it begin?

Comment: duplicate of: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13157/8775.

Comment: see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamsa

Comment: [What Is a Hamsa?](http://judaism.about.com/od/judaismbasics/a/whatisahamsa.htm) An amulet designed to protect against the *ayin hara* (evil eye) Many scholars believe that the hamsa predates both Judaism and Islam, possibly without origins in religion, although ultimately there is no certainty about its origins.